# require/import imports an empty object instead of Vue component

Tags: vuejs2, node-modules

I have a Vuejs project created with `vue init webpack` command.

Then, [vue-datetime-picker](https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/vue-datetime-picker) module is installed with

```
npm install --save vue-datetime-picker
```

Then inside a project component source file I'm trying to import the component

```
import VueDatetimePicker from 'vue-datetime-picker'
// OR
// var VueDatetimePicker = require('vue-datetime-picker')

console.log('VueDatetimePicker: ', VueDatetimePicker)
```

browser console output

```
VueDatetimePicker:  {}
```

the node module `src` folder content

```
node_modules/vue-datetime-picker/src$ ls
i18n/  
vue-datetime-picker.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using Vue.js 2, but this component is using Vue.js 1, it has a lot of change, you can read here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html .